# Persisting Cookies In An iOS Application?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I am going to use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` in an iOS App to manage cookies that are retrieved from a url, and I understand that it will manage cookies during your application's runtime. However, I was wondering if it's possible to persist cookies after the application has closed. And then read those cookies again when the app is opened again. Does `NSHTTPCookieStorage` persist cookies between app uses? Or just during the applications runtime? Do I need to use `CoreData` to persist these cookies?`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to re-set the cookies when your app is loaded. I use code like this:

```
NSData *cookiesdata = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MySavedCookies"];
if([cookiesdata length]) {
    NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cookiesdata];
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;

    for (cookie in cookies) {
        [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
    }
}
```

and it works just fine.

Comment: Is `MySavedCookies` already there? Or do I have to store that when my app is about to go inactive?

Comment: You have to save it yourself - It's just where I save mine.

Comment: Storing cookies in user defaults may be a security flaw as all plist can be accessed via tools like iFunBox etc.
They should be encrypted but the best behavior is to follow @gazreese answer.

Answer (score 118):

You shouldn't need to persist the cookies yourself as suggested in the other answer. `NSHTTPCookieStorage` will persist the cookies for you but you need to ensure that the cookies have an expiry date set on the server-side.

Cookies without an expiry date are considered 'session only' and will get cleared when you restart the app. You can check the 'session only' situation via a BOOL property in `NSHTTPCookie`. This is standard cookie stuff and not something specific to iOS.

Comment: Came here looking for this clarity, thanks. Interesting that it's cleared when the app is restarted. You can restart Chrome on desktop and still have a session open.

Comment: +1 I understand now why my cookies are no more there :). Thanks !!

Comment: You saved me a lot of time! Thanks!

Comment: @gazreese I am trying to encrypt the cookie files in iOS cordova application. Its working but only when app is in foreground. When I switch the app or press home button, new cookie file is created with same data. Can anybody guide me how I can encrypt the cookie files?

Comment: You made my day, thankyou!