# iOS web service login with cookie

Tags: php, ios, cocoa, cookies

I've got a login system for a website, I'm starting a PHP session server side and creating a cookie in PHP which is used to revive the PHP session when I come back later on.

I'm trying to reuse my code as the back end of an iOS application, but I'm having a hard time understanding just how it's working.

I've set up the following cookie manager, as I understand this should send cookies with my requests.

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

I don't need to set any cookies from the iPhone, I just need to make sure that my requests to my php files let those scripts access the cookies.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Depending on your use case you may also want to save your cookies somewhere and reload them when your app launches.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right, if I relaunch my application I'm getting a different PHPSESSID in the returned list of cookies. I just need to remember a user id and a hashed string in my cookies, and make sure they're accessible from my PHP when I make requests. When I relaunch the application I am getting a new PHPSESSID - suggesting that the relaunch did in fact not persist my cookies. Could you provide some references or a sample that I could use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked before: [Persisting Cookies In An iOS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application)

Essentially you need to save the cookie data somewhere. It could simply be a file using something like this:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:cookies toFile:dataFilePath];
```

In which case you would return the cookie data with something like:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *cookies = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:dataFilePath];
for (cookie in cookies) {
   [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
}
```

Your real-world scenario will dictate the best way to handle this, but hopefully the above gets you thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for you reply David, I did see that other post, and actually it isn't what I'm trying to achieve. I don't need to know anything about the cookies, all I need to do is make sure that my PHP back end web service can stick some cookies onto me and for these cookies to persist to the next time I request something from the web service. This is to make sure that I can login with my custom registration/login scripts on the server and persist the login with the help of cookies. So saving the cookie has no value. I actually needed to make sure the cookies expiry date was set

Comment: @Daniel So, if I am understanding this right you are not worried about persisting the cookies when closing and relaunching the app. What you are dealing with is getting cookies to work at all. Correct?

Comment: Almost, I still need the app to maintain the fact the web service saved a cookie on me, for this I needed to make sure the cookie had a correct expiry date in the future, otherwise is was a session only cookie and the application going to the background ended the session.

Comment: Okay, for some reason I thought that you had tried `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and needed an alternative. It sounds like your real concern was the use of session cookies rather than persistent cookies and that you have solved the issue.

Comment: That's the way the cookie crumbled... thanks for your involvement. Just to clear up any loose ends, I started by just adding the accept policy and I wanted to know if that was all I needed, it was, from the apps point of view, yet what I learnt here was the application going into the background ended the session, and with it all the session-only cookies. That's worthy of a post-it note

Comment: Though David's answer was about 2 years back i wanted to know the behavior on iOS7. My app supports iOS6 and 7 both. Do i still have to store cookies manually in userdefaults which app closed and load back upon re-launch.