# Can local storage be used to persist cache on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

As I read here http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2008/02/iphone-cache-performance.html
all is gone after reboot.

So can local storage be used to keep persistence somehow even after reboot (in UIWebView with a bit of Objective-C maybe) ? If yes any example ?

Comment: You can use NSHTTPCookieStorage.  Chech this [SO][1] Q&A.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just write to the application documents directory. This will persist through reboots.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
   NSDocumentDirectory,
   NSUserDomainMask, 
   YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

[yourFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks but then you load in webview ?

Comment: Right, and the html in the web view references the cached files. So you should write the html file into the cache so it can use relative paths.