# Save cookie persistence

Tags: swift, cookies

```
var url:NSURL=NSURL(string:"http://xxxxxxxx/index.php?s=/Public_verify.html")!
var data:NSData=NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
var img:UIImage=UIImage(data:data)!
self.Verify.setBackgroundImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal) 


var username=UserName.text
var password=PassWord.text
var verifycode=VerifyCode.text

let url=NSURL(string:"http://xxxxxxxx/index.php?s=/Public_doLogin.html")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)&verifyCode=\(verifycode)&ajax=1"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
              //cookie?
        }
        task.resume()
```

Code above, I used NSURLSession.sharedSession (). DataTaskWithRequest to POST login.
I quit APP, COOKIE disappears need to re-login
How to make cookie has been recorded, unless I log off the user?

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application. Make sure the server is setting an expiry date, otherwise the cookie is deemed "session only".