# Significant differences between Cookies and JWT for native mobile apps

Tags: ios, session, authentication, cookies, jwt

I have been using Cookies for authentication and session control in my web apps, and am content with its functionalities.

I was introduced by an iOS app developer that the new hot thing is JWT (JSON Web Token). He told me that JWT is *the way* of doing authentication and sessions for native mobile apps, and without giving specific examples, he suggested that both iOS and Android apps have various problems with Cookies.

So I looked up JWT, e.g. http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-introduction/ and https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/, and I failed to see why it is significant better (or even that different) than Cookies, and more specifically, why it does better in native mobile apps. It seems that, at least iOS, handles Cookies just fine ([Persisting Cookies In An iOS Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application)).

So my question is, for a native mobile app that interacts with a server-side API, what are the specific advantages and associated use cases for using JWT over Cookies for authentication and sessions? Please highlight the ones that Cookies simply cannot do or does it much worse.

Comment: There is at least one significant difference. You should consider auto-scaling web-apps (servers) sitting behind a load balancer. Unless you have some app-wide session handling set in place ("global" coockie storage...) it just might happen that authentication and a couple of first request go trough one server and then another request is routed to another server - with no authenticated session. One way to overcome this situation is JWT.

Comment: @rokjarc, thanks for pointing that out. I have been using Redis as a central store for session management, and that seems to be a norm these days. But I see your point.

Comment: Some web frameworks, such as Rails or Play in my experience, use cookie session (store encoded session data in a cookie). This technique does not require a central session store because session is decoded from cookie for every request (given that all servers use the same secret key for decoding). It is similar to JWT and imho better because client such as browser does not have to maintain the JWT token. I am researching to apply this technique to mobile app.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

<sub>We software developers (sometimes) have the tendency to apply the new hot thing everywhere we look; it's possibly a variation of the saying *if all we have is an hammer, everything looks like a nail* where in this case we just feel a desperate urge to use this new thing we learned about.</sub>

One interesting point about this comparison is that neither [JWT](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/) or Cookies are in fact authentication mechanisms on their own; the first just defines a [token format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and the second is an [HTTP state management mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265). Only this is sufficient to give us an indication that advocating that one is better than the other is wrong.

It's true however that both are vastly used in authentication systems.

Traditional server-side web application have used cookies to keep track of an authenticated user so that they were not forced to provide their credentials at every request. Normally, the content of the cookie would be an (hopefully) random generated unique identifier that the server would use to find session data stored on the server.

However, for a new type of web application - the API - it's more much more common to accept a token (in JWT format most of the times) as a way for the server to decide if it should grant access to who's making the request. The reason for this is possibly because while a traditional web application had one major type of client, the web browser, which has full support for cookies, the API's are generally used by much simpler HTTP clients that don't natively support cookies.

I think this is also why we could possibly argue that token based authentication makes more sense for native mobile applications. These applications generally depend on a server-side Web API and we've seen that if the API supports tokens it will increase the range of clients that can use it, so it's just the most practical thing to do.

In conclusion and to try to answer your concrete question, I would say JWT's do have an advantage over cookies on native mobile applications just because of the fact they are currently in very common use, this means more learning resources, SDK's, known pitfalls (mostly because someone else already did it and failed), etc.

Nonetheless, only use them if they give you the security assurances you need and end up simplifying your scenario. If you haven't gone through it already, I think you'll also appreciate [Cookies vs Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/).

Comment: absolutely awesome reply.

Comment: Seems like auth0 deleted their definitive guide. Maybe it was too controversial :D

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for Android but on iOS cookies work with `URLSession` as good as headers. Once you can utilize the (standard) API right (e.g. dedicated, properly configured session with cookie storage per web app...), iOS should be a rather negligible factor to this decision.