# NSUserDefaults to Store login Cookie?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I use NSUserDefaults to store parameters.

**What is the size of data I can store in the user default? Is it a good place to store the login cookie?**

Comment: Take a look at this previously asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597763/persisting-cookies-in-an-ios-application

Comment: Not secure. Please don't save passwords and emails there

Comment: I want to save a cookie there and not password! Where should I save the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all theres no space limit when storing into NSUserDefaults (obviously the device capacity).

Now about the cookie thats very confusing, if you are talking about store a bool to say if the user is registered or not UserDefaults is perfectly adaptable/applicable.

Comment: I want to store a cookie retrieved from the server to access the backend without login again.

Comment: In that case take a look into Daehn's link, you can Archieve the cookie into NSDATA and store that NSData into Defaults.

Comment: Where should I store the password?

Comment: You can also store the password in nsuserdefaults, but, depending on how important/secure you want your app to be you must use an encription, external library for passwords such as GSKeychain or even the iOS KeyChain services.